# RJDBC limiting rows from Netezza

Tags: netezza, rjdbc

I have an RJDBC connection to Netezza.  Queries that should return more than 256 rows are getting truncated to 256 rows.  I have tested the queries in SQuirrel and they work fine (return the correct number of rows - 600+).

I have also tried the following:

```
dbFetch(res, n=-1)

dbFetch(res, n=1000)

dbSendQuery(conn, "select ...", believeNRows=FALSE)
```

All of these simply return just the first 256 rows.  I am on a Mac so ODBC is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the JDBC driver from version 5 to version 7 resolved the issue.